# Display JSON Api conform errors

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework, json-api

I receive [JSON Api conform](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects-multiple-errors) errors from the backend:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": "400",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data/attributes/description"
      },
      "detail": "This field may not be null."
    },
    {
      "status": "400",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data/attributes/due-date"
      },
      "detail": "This field may not be null."
    },
    {
      "status": "400",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data/attributes/extra-comments"
      },
      "detail": "This field may not be null."
    },
    {
      "status": "400",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data/attributes/name"
      },
      "detail": "This field may not be null."
    },
    {
      "status": "400",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data/attributes/payment-type"
      },
      "detail": "This field may not be null."
    },
    {
      "status": "400",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data/attributes/price"
      },
      "detail": "This field may not be null."
    }
  ]
}
```

I try to show them in my template, as described in the [EmberData documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html):

```
{{#each model.errors.messages as |message|}}
  <div class="error">
    {{message}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Nothing is shown. I would say the `.errors` in the model are not populated, but I am not sure how to check this. How can I:

- display the received ajax reply?
- make sure that EmberData is processing the reply and populating `model.errors`?
- Show the processed `model.errors` in the console?
- Show the `model` and all properties?

In general, I am experiencing that new versions of Ember are very hard to debug. Whenever I show any Ember object in the console, I just see some `Computed` properties which are not expanded whenever I try to peek into them.

My backend is:

- Django 1.9
- with [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
- [django-rest-framework-json-api](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api)

### EDIT

This is the data that I am POSTing to the backend (JSONAPi conform):

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": null,
      "description": null,
      "extra-comments": null,
      "min-price": 30,
      "max-price": 3000,
      "price-step": 10,
      "price": null,
      "payment-type": null,
      "due-date": null
    },
    "relationships": {
      "seller": {
        "data": null
      },
      "artist": {
        "data": null
      },
      "subcategory": {
        "data": null
      }
    },
    "type": "projects"
  }
}
```

The backend is ok with this, detects the errors, and provides a JSON APi conform `errors` reply, as specified above.

Comment: You don't mention the [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) in your question, are you using it? It's by far the best way (IMHO) to inspect the state of an ember application.

Comment: @PedroRio: Yes, I am using it, but I am unable to see errors in my model

Comment: Can you use your developer tools in browser to see whether you are POSTing the data fields your backend is complaining or not?

Comment: I am POSTing them, and they have indeed errors, which is what I am testing right now. So POST data is ok, POST reply seems ok, but ember model has no populated errors.

Comment: OK, then this seems more like an ember problem than Django, best of luck  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I know what's happening (as it happened to me as well).

Change the HTTP error code from 400 to 422 (Unprocessable Entity) and check if it fixes the problem.

Also, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.2.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L783-L785) for the JSONAPIAdapter (which extends from the RestAdapter) I think I'm right.

```
isInvalid: function(status, headers, payload) {
   return status === 422;
},
```

This can be changed to (`adapters/application.js`):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

import config from '../config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
    host: config.API_HOST,
    namespace: config.API_NAMESPACE,
    isInvalid: function(status, headers, payload) {
        return status === 400 || status === 422;
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Not sure how to change the error code in my backend.

Comment: Maybe you could try some form of "intercepting proxy" to manually change the values returned by the backend just to check the result? Or use the chrome debugger at that line I pointed in the rest adapter and change the value there?

Comment: Great idea! I'll try that. But for a final solution I'll need to tweak my backend I guess.

Comment: I guess you could probably create your own adapter (extending from the JSONAPI adapter) and [override the `isInvalid`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_isInvalid) method to check for your particular status code

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that right now. BTW, where did you encounter this problem? Also django-rest-framework + EmberData?

Comment: [Katharsis](http://katharsis.io) (Java library for JSONAPI) with Play Framework + Ember Data.

Comment: I have updated your answer with a working example. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, thanks for updating my answer! Good luck with your ember app!

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I have done this on the django side:

```
from rest_framework_json_api.exceptions import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # DRF returns 400, but EmberData wants 422. I will force a 422, always.
    # Call the rest_framework_json_api's exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    # TODO: is this correct? 422 in all exception cases?!
    response.status_code = 422
    return response
```