# Return 422 status code in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework, json-api

For interoperability with EmberData [it seems](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.2.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L783-L785) I need to [reply with 422](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34609452/647991) (`Unprocessable Entity`) instead of 400 (`Bad Request`) whenever validation errors occur. I have two questions:

- How can I specify the response status code when using a [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)?
- Why is the 422 not listed in the list of [possible return codes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/#client-error-4xx)?

And bonus:

- Why is EmberData expecting 422? This is not part of the JSONAPi spec, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 8):

422 is part of the WebDAV DRF which error codes aren't in DRF.
This doesn't stop you to use it. They are just a human readable version of the number itself.

One option would be to override `rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError.status_code` and set it to 422.

Edit - Changing the default error code:

```
# At the top of a views.py file, by the ends of import add:
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
ValidationError.status_code = 422
```

Comment: Thanks. I found a related link too: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3587. But this begs the question: why is EmberData using (actually, **requiring**) a status code which is not part of the http standard?

Comment: I have found the definition of ValidationError (https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L68), but this is imported directly by the django-rest-framework, and there seems to be no method of configuring the ValidationError class, so even if I provide my own subclassed version, I have no idea how to tell drf to use it. Do you have an idea how to achive that?

Comment: Thanks, but I have a general python importing question: if I do that in one view file (views1.py) and I do not do it in another view file (views2.py), what is the status_code in ValidationError class in views2.py? Is it changed or the original? I would say changing it in any view file would change it globally (there is only one ValidationError class), so that would force all my drf views to use the 422 status_code, right? In my case that's ok, since I am only interfacing to EmberData, but I would say this is not a very clean way of changing the status_code, in a general way?

Comment: The code snippet will alter *all* the ValidationError instances provided the instance itself doesn't override it after. In short, once it's done one time all the ValidationError will return a 422.

Comment: If you needed a finer grained error code, it'll be trickier and you'll probably have to override the default exception handler to choose which return code you'd use according to other conditions.

Comment: I chose the 2nd solution (although it's a hack) because I don't have to change the virtual environment in each machine.